# Reading from Rs232 getting two white spaces after string

Tags: c#

I'm trying to read from rs232. For some reason, and sometimes(not always) after reading string it takes two white spaces.

```
public static void Modem(Main ths)
    {


                mySerialPort = new SerialPort(Connection.ModemSerialPort);
                mySerialPort.BaudRate = 115200;
                mySerialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
                mySerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
                mySerialPort.DataBits = 8;
                mySerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;

                mySerialPort.Open();
                mySerialPort.WriteLine("AT+VCID=1\r");
                mySerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);



    }
    private static void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
            string indata = sp.ReadExisting();

            if (indata.Contains("=") == true)
            {


                string str = indata.Split('=').Last().Trim(); 
          }
```

So my result is 'test '

I dont know why happening this.

Comment: Do you know if the spaces are being sent, or if they're added when you read from the serial port?

Comment: How is your result 'test'? I don't see that anywhere in your code.

Comment: The way this code uses ReadExisting() is not correct.  Pretty standard bug.  You only get back what is "existing" and that is completely unpredictable.  Usually only 1 or 2 characters.  But seems to work when when debugging, that slows down the code enough.  When talking to a modem you should always favor ReadLine(), provides you with the complete modem response.

Comment: I'm using result to insert it inside sql server. But when i'm looking for this string i cant found it.Cause ti takes two more characters invisible to me